rust returning a reference to a integer from a function
In this deref trait, reference to 42 is returned.
Is the value 42 created on stack?
Or is it just a 'static literal of i32 that's stored in executive binary?
It seems later is the case, because otherwise it will get freed after function return.
use std::ops::Deref;

struct Curse<T>(T);

impl<T> Deref for Curse<T> {
    type Target = usize;
    
    fn deref(&self) -> &<Self as Deref>::Target {
        &42 // wat
    }
   
}

fn main() {
    let a = 123;
    let b = Curse(a);
    let c = *b;
    
    println!("{a} {c}");
}

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=aa605847795ee1a34bbad724e4f75ea9
